# How to properly align second arrow from same block?

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker

I have the following block diagram obtained using tikz:

[image]

How can I align the arrow going from the "Parameters Adaptation Law" block to the "Controllers Parameter Update" block in order no to be on top of the arrow going to the "Parameters Adaptation Block" ? Here is the script producing the block diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
                node distance = 15mm and 10mm,
                start chain = going right,
                arr/.style = {-Latex},
                %block/.style = {draw, minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em},
                sum/.style = {circle, draw, node contents={}},    
                        ]
                \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]        
                \coordinate (in);
                \node (n1) [sum];
                \node (n2) [block, right=of n1] {\textlatin{Controller}};                      
                \node (n3) [block, right=of n2] {\textlatin{Plant}};
                \node (n4) [block,right=of n3] {\textlatin{Low Pass Filter}};
                \coordinate (out);
                \end{scope}
                \path   (in) to [pos=0.35,"$r \ \ \ \ +$"] (n1)
                        (n1) to ["$e$"{name=error}]     (n2)
                        (n2) to ["$u$"{name=control signal}] (n3)
                        (n3) to ["$y$"{name=plant output}] (n4)
                        (n4) to ["$y_f$"{name=y}]        (out);         
                \draw [->] (y) -- ++ (0,-2) -| node [pos=0.95] {$-$} (n1);
                \node (n5) [block, above=of plant output] {\textlatin{Parameters Adaptation Law}};
                \node (n6) [block, above=of n2] {\textlatin{Controller Parameters Update}};

                \draw [->] (y) |- (n5);
                \draw [->] (n6) -- node[anchor=east] {$\hat{K}$} (n2);
                \draw [->] (control signal) |- (n5);
                \draw [->] (n5) -- node[anchor=south] {$\hat{A}$} (n6);                        
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A code without preamble always requires some amount of guess work (as well as unnecessary work). I dropped the `\textlatin{...}` commands because I did not know which version of `babel` you are using. The answer to the question is probably something along the lines

```
\draw [->] (control signal) |- ([yshift=-1em]n5.west);
```

but there were several additional issues. The most important one is that you can use *either* `chains` *or* `positioning` for the node positioning. So in the scope of the chain, do *not* use `right of` because this leads to slight misalignments of the nodes (which is why one of the arrows wasn't perfectly horizontal).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,babel,chains,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
                node distance = 15mm and 10mm,
                start chain = going right,
                arr/.style = {->},>=Latex,
                block/.style = {draw, minimum height=3em, minimum
                width=4em,align=center,fill=blue!20},
                sum/.style = {circle, draw, node contents={}},    
                        ]
                \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]        
                \coordinate (in);
                \node (n1) [sum];
                \node (n2) [block] {Controller};                      
                \node (n3) [block] {Plant};
                \node (n4) [block] {Low Pass Filter};
                \coordinate (out);
                \end{scope}
                \path   (in) to [pos=0.35,"$r~~~+$"] (n1)
                        (n1) to ["$e$"{name=error}]     (n2)
                        (n2) to ["$u$"{name=control signal}] (n3)
                        (n3) to ["$y$"{name=plant output}] (n4)
                        (n4) to ["$y_f$"{name=y}]        (out);         
                \draw [->] (y) -- ++ (0,-2) -| node [pos=0.95] {$-$} (n1);
                \node (n5) [block, above=of plant output] {Parameters\\
                        Adaptation\\ Law};
                \node (n6) [block] at (n5-|n2) {Controller\\ Parameters\\ Update};

                \draw [->] (y) |- (n5);
                \draw [->] (n6) -- node[anchor=east] {$\hat{K}$} (n2);
                \draw [->] (control signal) |- ([yshift=-1em]n5.west);
                \draw [->] (n5) -- node[anchor=south] {$\hat{A}$} (n6);                        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am really sorry. I forgot to include that. However, thank you for the great answer!